# How to connect sql server with php using xampp?

Tags: php, sql-server, phpmyadmin, xampp, sqlsrv

I am trying to connect my SQL server with PHP using Xampp. I have already uploaded dll files in the ext folder but I am unable to connect it.
My PHP version is 7.2.6.
Uploaded dll files are - php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts.dll, php_sqlsrv_72_ts.dll.
I have written this code to connect my SQL database with PHP-

```html
<?php   
$serverName = "INDO-SERV\SQLEXPRESS,1443";  
$uid = "sa";     
$pwd = "XXXXXX";    
$databaseName = "web";  
$connectionInfo = array("UID" => $uid, "PWD" => $pwd, "Database"=>$databaseName);  
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);  
if( $conn )  
{  
     echo "Connection established.\n";  
}  
else  
{  
     echo "Connection could not be established.\n";  
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));  
}  
sqlsrv_close( $conn);  
?>
```

I am getting this error when I had tried this-

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   sqlsrv_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\biometric\db.php:7 Stack trace: #0
>   {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\biometric\db.php on line 7.

Anyone has an idea where I am doing wrong or how to connect with the database.

Comment: So what is the actual error you see? What message? We cannot _guess_ that...

Comment: And what "dll files" did you upload where and why?

Comment: I have updated the post please check it once.

Comment: @SahilVerma Your PHP Driver is not installed correctly. Run `<?php phpinfo();?>` and check for 'sqlsrv' section in the output.

Comment: I have already installed the driver with a matching version of PHP. My current PHP version is 7.2.

Answer (score 6):

Installation of PHP Driver for SQL Server (`sqlsrv` and/or `pdo_sqlsrv` PHP extensions) can be done following the next steps:

- Based on [Microsoft PHP Drivers for SQL Server Support Matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-drivers-for-sql-server-support-matrix?view=sql-server-2017#php-version-support) download appropriate version of this driver. In your case - version 5.2 or 5.3 (32-bit or 64-bit also depends on PHP version).
- Download and install an appropriate ODBC driver - see [System Requirements for the Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-2017)
- [Load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/loading-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-2017) PHP Driver for SQL Server as PHP extension.
- Restart Apache

Check the configuration with `<?php phpinfo();?>`. There should be a section with name `pdo_sqlsrv` (if you use PDO) and/or `sqlsrv` (without PDO).

Answer (score 2):

my XAMPP version is 7.0.13

1- Download and Install "SQLSRV40.EXE" on this path:

```
D:\xampp\php\ext
```

2- Download and Install "msodbcsql.msi"

3- Edit file ":\xampp\php\php.ini" and add this extensions :

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll
extension=php7ts.dll
```

4- restart xampp

> Note: "SQLSRV40.EXE" Contain this extensions:
>   php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll , php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll , php7ts.dll

Answer (score 1):

Download driver from:

https://download.microsoft.com/download/f/4/d/f4d95d48-74ae-4d72-a602-02145a5f29c8/SQLSRV510.ZIP

- Unzip the files
- Copy the dll files in C:\xampp\php\ext\
- Open with your favourite editor the file php.ini located in C:\xampp\php\
- Insert the extensions:

> ```
> extension=pdo_sqlsrv_74_ts_x64 
> extension=sqlsrv_74_ts_x64
> ```

- Restart Apache and PHP

Answer (score 0):

For the new comers;

You can setup driver and integrate it as in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=10zj58mOHnQ) explains so in a nutshell;

- You should find [drivers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/download-drivers-php-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) for php - sql server integration depending to your environment ([versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-2017)) at links and download the driver that suits for your environment.
- You should move the driver file (.dll for windows case) to php/ext folder.
- You need to change php.ini as entering a new extension (for example extension=php_sqlsrv_7_ts.dll) by giving your exact file name you have moved to php/ext.
- Restart your local server and you should see this extension in phpinfo(), if you can see it's there, you can connect to your db with your credentials and it's done.

Credits goes to creator of the video (applause) :)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31093973)

Comment: Thank you for your meaningful feedback, I changed my answer.