# How to connect to SQL Server database with PHP

Tags: php, html, sql-server

I want to feed my html page with data that came from SQLServer database. I wanted to use Javascript, but I've seen that wasn't the best option. So I tried with php (that is not my favorite language).

I tried this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>


    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="res/MPS.png" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <link rel="icon" href="res/MPS.png" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <title>Historique</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
      $servername = "192.168.102.232\SQLEXPRESS"
      $connectionInfo = array("Database" => "PROFACE", "UID" => "userName", "PWD" => "password");
      $conn = sqlsrv_connect($servername, $connectionInfo);

      if($conn) {
        echo "Connexion OK. <br/>"; 
      } else {
        echo "Connexion NOK <br/>";
        die( print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
      }
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

UserName and password are replace with real informations in my original code.

This code doesn't work fine, and I have this error :
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$connectionInfo' (T_VARIABLE)`

I don't see what is the problem and if my code could work.

Comment: U are missing a semicolon on $servername = "192.168.102.232\SQLEXPRESS";

Comment: Oh yes indeed, basic error. But now I have ``` Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()```

Comment: is it enabled in `php.ini`?

Comment: I have no idea ...

Comment: Use PDO instead. It's better.

Comment: @MissKnacki PHP Driver for SQl Server is not installed. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53664188/how-to-connect-sql-server-with-php-using-xampp/53680488#53680488) may help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP code should be like this

```
<?php
      $servername = "192.168.102.232\SQLEXPRESS";
      $connectionInfo = array("Database" => "PROFACE", "UID" => "userName", "PWD" => "password");
      $conn = sqlsrv_connect($servername, $connectionInfo);

      if($conn) {
        echo "Connexion OK. <br/>"; 
      } else {
        echo "Connexion NOK <br/>";
        die( print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
      }
    ?>
```

You forgot to add semicolon on this line

```
$servername = "192.168.102.232\SQLEXPRESS"
```