# Xampp not connecting to SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server

I have loaded the SQL drivers in `php/etc` folder and also have edited path in `php.ini`. I can see `sqlsrv` in php info as well.

[image]

This is the code that I am using to connect to SQL Server on another server.

I tried server name "10.10.10.38:1433" this also nothing worked for me.

```
    $serverName = "10.10.10.38,1433";
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"DBNAME", "UID"=>"USERNAME", "PWD"=>"PASSWORD");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
   
    if ($conn) {
       echo "Connection established.<br />";
    } else {
       echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
       die (print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
```

But I am getting following error:

[image: error message]

Please help to resolve the issue.

Comment: People will be able to read your error much easier if you post as text instead of image.

Comment: A possible [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53664188/how-to-connect-sql-server-with-php-using-xampp/53680488#53680488), but the error is clear -  you need to install the appropriate version of the ODBC Driver.

Comment: i have tried everything my php verison is 7.2 and i have installed same version but still not able to sort it out. i have done this on some other applications also and its working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled `pdo_sqlsrv` ?

Have you installed ODBC drivers?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

After installing the right ODBC drivers as Maxi Malvido told you you can use a PDO connection:

```
<?php
$conn = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server=yourserver;  Database=test', 'login', 'password');

if ($conn)
{
    echo "Connection established";
}
else {
    echo "Connection not established";
}

?>
```