# Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect - Driver already installed on php7.2 - Wamp 3.1.7

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, sqlsrv, php-7.2

I have the error:

> Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect

, but the SQLSRV driver is already installed.

I check the available drivers and the result is:

```js
Array
(
    [0] => mysql
    [1] => sqlite
    [2] => sqlsrv
)
```

In phpINFO:

[image]

For this, I don't understand why sqlsrv_connect is not working ?
Thanks
Edited :
[image]

Comment: `Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect` error message means that the PHP Driver is not correctly installed. You may check the configuration with a very simple PHP script - `<?php phpinfo();?>`. There must be a section `sqlsrv` and/or `pdo_sqlsrv` (depending on configuration).

Comment: My phpinfo in edited question

Comment: Only the PDO part of the driver is installed. Edit `php.ini` and include `php_sqlsrv_....dll` extension.

Comment: Additional [information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53664188/how-to-connect-sql-server-with-php-using-xampp/53680488#53680488).

Comment: Okay thanks, after completing the installation , I have this error (in Edited Question )

Comment: Simply download and install the appropriate ODBC Driver.

Comment: I Install the dll on the link https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712    , not solve the issue. Is there any module to activate on apache ?

Comment: You need to: 1) Install ODBC Driver 13.1 needed for version 5.6 of the PHP driver; 2) Restart the Apache service

Comment: It work after install ODBC Driver, thanks ;)