# How can we start a connection in mysql and php

Tags: mysql

Can anyone tell me about how to build a connection between mysql and php page.

Please help me with this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to connect sql server with php using xampp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53664188/how-to-connect-sql-server-with-php-using-xampp)

Answer (score 0):

Make conn.php file with this code inside and use $conn variable to prepare queries using prepared statement

```
if(!defined("connection")){
    header('Location:error.php');
    exit();
}

define("host","localhost");
define("user","mysql_user");
define("pass","password");
define("dbname","database_name");

$conn=new mysqli(host,user,pass,dbname);

if($conn->connect_error){
    die("Failed to connect");
    exit();
}

mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8mb4");
```

Use conn.php and $conn variable like this

Page.php

```
 require_once("conn.php");

 if($stmt = $conn->prepare($query)){
     echo "prepared";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To start a connection You Might do Following code:-

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "test";
$password = "test";
$dbname = "test";
//change test with your server details//

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);

if ($conn)
{
    //echo "connection ok";
}
else
{
    echo "connection Failed";
}


?>
```

hope this code would help you .