# Connecting SQL Server 2014 to PHP 7.4

Tags: php, sql-server, xampp, sqlsrv

I need to link SQL server with my PHP I have downloaded the drivers and placed them in the `C:\xampp\php\ext` file already.

Updated the `php.ini` file as well:

```
extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext"

;SQL Server Ext
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_74_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_74_ts_x64.dll
```

but I get this error:

> PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_pdo_sqlsrv_74_ts_x64.dll' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_74_ts_x64.dll (The specified module could not be found.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_pdo_sqlsrv_74_ts_x64.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_sqlsrv_74_ts_x64.dll' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_sqlsrv_74_ts_x64.dll (The specified module could not be found.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_sqlsrv_74_ts_x64.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0

I am using `PHP V 7.4.27` and my `PHP Extension build is TS`
My architecture is `x64`

Comment: You probably need to install the appropriate ODBC Driver. A similar [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53664188/how-to-connect-sql-server-with-php-using-xampp/53680488#53680488).

Comment: msobdcsql.sql and sqlncli.msi drivers are also installed but still same error, I don't know what I am doing wrong :( tried almost all the solutions found online

Comment: I cannot see the pdo_sqlsrvr or sqlsrvr in my phpinfo()