# How do I connect to SQL server with PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server

I work with xampp PHP 8.1
I'm trying to connect to SQL Server.
I downloaded the drivers, but when starting xampp I get the message (in the log file) that the drivers are not found.
I have no idea what the problem is, because the extension file path is correct, the drivers are correct, but they won't load.

Comment: An old [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53664188/how-to-connect-sql-server-with-php-using-xampp/53680488#53680488), if you are using the PHP Driver for SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to a SQL Server database using PHP, you can use the sqlsrv_connect() function.

an exaple:

```
$serverName = "serverName\instanceName";
$databaseName = "databaseName";

$connectionOptions = array(
  "Database" => $databaseName,
  "Uid" => "username",
  "PWD" => "password"
);

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);

if ($conn) {
  // Connection was successful
} else {
  // Connection failed
  die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Comment: This does not resolve issues for the `pdo_sqlsrv` or `sqlsrv` extensions failing to load due to missing drivers.

Answer (score 0):

In order to connect with SQL database, you need your given DB username, password and PHP sqlsvr_connect() function.

```
$serverName = "serverName\\sqlexpress"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName", "user_id"=>"your_user_name", "passwod"=>"your_password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection was successful! <br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection was not successful! <br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Comment: This does not resolve issues for the `pdo_sqlsrv` or `sqlsrv` extensions failing to load due to missing drivers.